# DFT LT and ZT of an array of data

Tags: laplace-transform, fourier-transform, z-transform

Let us say I have an array of $10$ elements $= \{1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45\}$.

How can I get its Fourier transformed array, Laplace transformed array and $Z$-transformed array?

Do I need any additional parameter to calculate DFT, LT and ZT of above array?

Comment: The DFT (the algorithm is called FFT) sends  your vector $x$ to a complex vector of same size. The other interesting maps send $x$ to the analytic functions  $X(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x_n z^{-n},L(s) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x_n e^{-sn}$ and to the periodic function $Y(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x_n e^{-2i \pi nt}$.  The DFT is the vector $y_k=Y(k/N)$.